# What should return the Grape rescue_from :all block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, grape-api

The Grape documentation says that:
`The rescue_from block must return a Rack::Response object, call error! or re-raise an exception.`

but if we use the `rescue_from` method only to log things and we want to keep the original HTTP answer what should we return ?

If I rethrow the catched exception, it does not keep the original behavior. 
For example, some of my tests generate `400` responses but with:

```
rescue_from :all do |e|
  Rails.logger.error(e)
  raise e
end
```

They catch `500` responses.

The better solution I found to reproduce the original behavior is this code:

```
rescue_from :all do |e|
  Rails.logger.error(e)
  if e.respond_to?(:status)
    error!(e.to_json, e.status, e.headers, e.backtrace)
  else
    error! "Internal Server Error"
  end
end
```

I should check if the catched exception responds to `status` because it could be a RuntimeError for example, and RuntimeError does not answer to `status`.

Am I doing this right ? Or there is a better solution to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is answered in https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape/pull/939, pointed from https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape/issues/1300.